# How can I use onchange to feed javascript the users selection in a dropdown list?

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables, onchange

I know this question is simple, but I couldn't find it elsewhere so I thought it would be appropriate to ask.

I have a simple drop down list.  I use onchange to trigger an event when the selection is changed.  I want to know what I need to do in order to turn the selection into a variable within javascript.  So that I can use that variable to do something else (specifically to populate another dropdown list using a switch statement).

Thanks

Comment: You want to get the `<select>` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
var optionSelected = 0;

var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');

select.onchange = function() {
    optionSelected = this.value;
    alert(optionSelected);
}​​​​​;​
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vTDAQ/1/